# Finding when and where conflict happened

Tags: git, version-control, merge, terminal

I been working with repo lately and another developer had some conflict unresolved on branch B, now as i am new to beanstalkapp GIT, i have tried using my knowledge of `git diff` , `git RESET` etc, but nothing. Even my conflict markers don't show, This is a strange kind of behaviour. I want to find out, what is the difference that is causing the conflict and when and which user changed that conflicted file. Even when i do git git reset -- HEAD sha-1, nothing happens. If i do a push, i get the following long message

> warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in Git
>   2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message and maintain the traditional behavior, use:
>
> git config --global push.default matching
>
> To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:
>
> git config --global push.default simple
>
> When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
>   to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.
>
> Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
>   behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
>   remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.
>
> See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further
>   information. (the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the
>   similar mode 'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older
>   versions of Git)
>
> fatal: The current branch b has no upstream branch. To
>   push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin b
> ```

**Summarizing Question:** My task is to reset the head to a sha-1 where i think the conflict didn't happen, and if it didn't make it the head so the repo on local as well as on remote are in sync, removing the conflict.
Also i am unable to understand the [image: following] image from my repo, where it says

```
32 behind 10 ahead
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @BjörnKautler i edited the question, to highlight. basically i want to find out conflict, find out where it happen and sync both of my repo.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect

Comment: @choroba Git docs are confusing to me. Sorry don't know how to understand it.

Comment: @choroba i wanna find out first, where conflict happened and on what file, i reckon that bicest don't do that?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reset the current branch to `sha-1` and also update your working tree accordingly, you use `git reset --hard sha-1`.

The message you get on push is just that you didn't tell gradle where to push to and it also tells you how to fix it.

The `32 behind 10 ahead` message means, that the remote branch your displayed local branch is tracking has 32 new commits that you didn't merge or rebase onto yet and that you have 10 commits in your displayed local branch that are not pushed to the remote yet.

The `Conflicts` message in your screenshot probably means that if you merge or rebase, you will get conflict as the 32 commits on the remote branch and the 10 commits in your local branch have conflicting changes. As soon as you do a merge or rebase (or pull, as it is fetch+merge or fetch+rebase depending on configuration and parameters) you will probably get presented the conflicts by git and can resolve them accordingly manually or with a merge tool like e. g. P4Merge (which is the best free diff and merge tool I know).

*Disclaimer:* I don't know beanstalkapp, just interpreting what I see in your screenshot.

Comment: I tried `git reset --hard sha-1` but i see conflict on my repo. Like it was before, i didn't understand about `32 behind 10 ahead`

Comment: "didn't" or "still do not"? What means "I see conflict"? How do you see the conflict? Are there conflict markers your buddy checked in, or do you have actual conflicted files, or what?

Comment: Still do not. I do not know which files are conflicted.

Comment: Well, what don't you understand? I described its meaning. Which part don't you understand? What is still unclear? You say "I see conflict" and "I do not know which files are conflicted". This still does not answer my question "How do you see the conflict?" from my last comment.

Comment: "How do you see the conflict", i see it on my beanstalkapp branches page, as screenshot in the question displays.

Comment: Ah, now I know what you meant. I udpated my answer.